# Weird behavior from print function in Python: OSError [WinError 87]

Tags: python, cmd

#### Background

When trying to print a certain string, the python interpreter completely breaks down. No subsequent print or repr operations work, display is bugged etc.

This error has been only reproduced in Windows 10, Python 3.7.4. Online interpreters handle it fine.

#### Minimum reproducible code:

```py
a = b'@badge-info=;badges=;color=#1E90FF;display-name=HuwoBot;emotes=;flags=;id=ace1f2cc-54ac-4889-8d25-fc64cacc3f8c;mod=0;room-id=22484632;subscriber=0;tmi-sent-ts=1587751046231;turbo=0;user-id=64313471;user-type= :huwobot!huwobot@huwobot.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #forsen :57 users failed to beat the raid level [1505] - No experience rewarded!\xf0\x9f\x92\x80 \xf3\xa0\x80\x80\r'

print(a.decode('utf-8'))
```

Note: I encoded the string in UTF-8 to post it here. The UTF-8 encoding as far as I know has nothing to do with the error.

Note2: This error doesn't occur without the print, i.e. `a.decode('utf-8')`.

Note3: The weird thing thing about this string is that by removing any character besides the last one can't produce the error.

#### After the error

[image: bug]

Things I did after the error:

- Printed a string, this resulted in the same error.
- Typed `'abc'`, this resulted in the same error.
- Exited the console, this raised the error again and printed the two strings that were not printed.

#### My questions are

- What exactly causes this error?
- Why does this error completely destroy the shell?

Comment: Could be an issue with not having a font installed that support the characters you're trying to display, or the shell not being configured to use them.

Comment: Your second to last character is `\U000e0000`, an invalid unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tags_(Unicode_block), characters like those you are trying to print (`\U000e0000` in particular) are marked as non-assigned.
[image: Unicode block]

Most websites
(e.g. https://fileformat.info) mark these characters as invalid. For example, [\U000e0000](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0000/index.htm) is marked as an "invalid Unicode character", while [\U000e0001](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0001/index.htm) is marked as a "valid Unicode character".

The problem most likely occurs when python/windows tries to interpret these characters - perhaps they signal to perform some action? In order to fix this, you can replace these characters with something else. By default, Unicode usually uses the "replacement character" [\uFFFD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) to replace characters whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode. Otherwise, you can simply remove these characters.

```py
import re

invalid_unicode_re = re.compile(u'[\U000e0000\U000e0002-\U000e001f]', re.UNICODE)

def replace_invalid_unicode(text, replacement_char=u'\uFFFD'):
    return invalid_unicode_re.sub(replacement_char, text)

# Example use-case:
text = b'@badge-info=;badges=;color=#1E90FF;display-name=HuwoBot;emotes=;flags=;id=ace1f2cc-54ac-4889-8d25-fc64cacc3f8c;mod=0;room-id=22484632;subscriber=0;tmi-sent-ts=1587751046231;turbo=0;user-id=64313471;user-type= :huwobot!huwobot@huwobot.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #forsen :57 users failed to beat the raid level [1505] - No experience rewarded!\xf0\x9f\x92\x80 \xf3\xa0\x80\x80\r'

safe_to_print = replace_invalid_unicode(text.decode('utf-8')) # use replacement character
print(safe_to_print)

safe_to_print = replace_invalid_unicode(text.decode('utf-8'), '') # remove character
print(safe_to_print)
```